# Moments of a positive random variable

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose one is handed a list of $K$ numbers, with a claim that these numbers are the first $K$ moments of a *positive* random variable $X$  (meaning there is 0 probability that $X<0$).

What is the strongest possible test that one could run on this list to test this claim? (We do not know any additional information about $X$.)
The most obvious thing to check first is that all the moments are positive.
A better test would involve checking that Jensen’s inequalities are satisfied. What is the most powerful test?

In general, there is a convex "allowed region” in the $K$-dimensional space of possible moments of $X$. Is there a good way to characterize this space?

Comment: Your question is too unspecific.In which field of research do you need the answers?

Comment: What is the region for $K=2,3,4$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- do you want to test if it is possible for there to exist any $X$ with these moments, or are you also given a particular $X$ (say you are given i.i.d. observations) and you want to test if it has these moments?

Comment: You are aware of the k  infinite versions of this problem ?  EG, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem

Comment: @usul I am interested in the former, e.g., does there exist any positive real $X$ with these moments. I have updated the question to clarify it slightly.

Comment: @mike is the multi-variate existence version of the problem also known for infinite k?

Comment: @Seva - my answer gives what seems to be the region for $K=1,2,3,4$

Answer (score 6):

This is known as the *truncated* Stieltjes moment problem, and there is a necessary and sufficient condition taking the form of a semidefinite program. See Section 5 of the [classic paper](https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/v017n4/0603CURTO.pdf) by Curto and Fialkow.

Answer (score 1):

Seva asked for the region when $K=2,3,4$

Empirically it seems

$$m_1 > 0$$

$$m_2 > m_1^2$$

$$m_3 > \dfrac{m_2^2}{m_1}$$

$$m_4 > \dfrac{m_3^2+m_2^3-2m_1 m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_1^2}$$

and while it is possible to turn one of these inequalities into an equality for a particular moment, that then fixes every higher moment, with

- $m_1=0 \implies m_2=0$ and $m_3=0$ and $m_4=0$
- $m_2=m_1^2  \implies m_3=m_1^3$ and $m_4=m_1^4$
- $m_3=\frac{m_2^2}{m_1}  \implies m_4=\frac{m_2^3}{m_1^2}$

It also seems empirically that it is possible for find an example for $X$ with the first $K$ given moments where $X$ can take $\lceil (K+1)/2\rceil$ possible non-negative values with associated probabilities (if $K$ is even then one of the values can be $0$), where this example can then give the boundary for the next higher moment. Finding the example involves solving a set of polynomial simultaneous equations.